# What can I do one day in Tehran?

Tags: iran, tehran

A group of tourists are going to have a full day staying Tehran, What can day do in that one day? How can they enjoy that day in Tehran?

Answer (score 2):

You could book a tour taking you around certain places in Tehran. On [this page](https://www.uppersia.com/Iran-day-tours/tehran-tours.html) there are tour options from 4 to 6 hours, and I assume there'd be many agencies willing to arrange group tours in case you have specific needs or preferences.